# C++ template inheritance hides template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
template <typename>
struct B
{
    constexpr static int T = 5;
};

template <int T>
struct D : B<int>
{
    constexpr static int value = T;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << D<7>::value << std::endl; // 5, how to get 7 ?
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/OjncsE)

As I have recently learned that the template parameters of a template derived class get checked after the names in the base class during lookup. That being said, is there anyway to *qualify* the name `T` initializing `value` to refer to the template parameter `T` of the derived class?

EDIT:

So far from discussions in the comments it seems that the only way to achieve this is by making the base class type/value dependent which will delay the lookup to the names of the base (to the instantiation phase) and thus making the only available value for T is the template parameter.

Comment: TIL... Interesting question.

Comment: No need for `B` to be a template by the way, a simple `class` has the same behaviour.

Comment: If I understand the problem, can't you just use a different name for the template parameter?

Comment: what If you don't know what the base declares?

Comment: In other words, you want to check `B::T`, don't you?

Comment: I want to be able to refer to the template type T or the member T in the base class

Comment: `struct D : B< decltype(B<void>::T) >`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question but I think `decltype` does what you want:

```
template <int T>
struct D : B<decltype(T)>
{
    constexpr static decltype(T) value = T;
};
```

Comment: Actually, you are solving OP's problem that `value` is equal to the template parameter `T` instead of base `T`.

Comment: What the... OH. You're artificially making `B<int>` dependent on `T` so that its scope will *not* be considered unless qualified... Nasty!

Comment: also you don't need the second decltype, AFAIK making the base class type dependent is enough

Comment: @Quentin Do you know why `decltype(T)` is considered dependent?

Comment: anyway, this solves the issue but it seems like a workaround to me. I would have preferred some way to really qualify what you want instead of making the base class type dependent

Comment: @Rakete1111 there seems to be quite a bit of fuzziness around value-dependent and type-dependent names. I had [a question based around that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37563745/3233393) to which the answer amounted to "well, no-one ever tried to do something that weird, so it's just not supported".

Comment: @mkmostafa Look at `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same` if you don't want to depend on parent types but want to check.

Answer (score 1):

Because `B` is template, you can modify it to make it a dependent base class of `D`:

```
template <typename, int = 0>
struct B {
    constexpr static int T = 5;
};

template <int T>
struct D : B<int, T> {
    constexpr static int value = T; // name lookup of base T is deferred
};
```

Comment: similar solution also but you made it *value* dependent?

Answer (score 0):

To refer to value `T` of template `B` (which doesn't depend on `B`'s template parameter):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename>
struct B
{
    constexpr static int T = 5;
};

template <int T>
struct D : B<decltype(B<void>::T)>
{
    constexpr static int value = T;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << D<7>::value << std::endl;
}
```

To refer type of template parameter `T` of template `D`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename>
struct B
{
    constexpr static int T = 5;
};

template <int T>
struct D : B<decltype(T)>
{
    constexpr static int value = T;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << D<7>::value << std::endl;
}
```